# Видео (WebView) в полноэкранном режиме не до конца масштабируется под размер экрана

Tags: java, android, webview

Пишу клиент для сайта. Есть WebView в который грузится контент, в том числе видео. Реализовал чтобы работал полноэкранный режим, но видео разворачивается не во всю ширину экрана. По бокам остается пространство. Прошу помочь советом, что сделал не так или куда смотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:padding="8dp">

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mFullscreenViewCallback;
private FrameLayout mFullScreenContainer;
private View mFullScreenView;
private WebView mWebView;

private static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 2;
private static final int ERROR = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mFullScreenContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_container);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    new getHtml().execute();
}

private class getHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    Elements tfa;
    Elements title;
    Elements comments;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DescriptionActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            Uri urls = getIntent().getData();
            String url = urls.toString();

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .get();

            title = doc.select(".c1-post").select("span");
            tfa = doc.select(".c1-post-data");
            comments = doc.select(".content").select(".comments");


            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("Unknown Host Exception", "Network error", e);
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", "Failed to load HTML", e);
            return ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "An exception occured", e);
            return ERROR;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (result == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Network connection error. Check your internet connection and try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unknown error. Failed to load.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 1) {

            String comqqq = Jsoup.clean(comments.toString(), Whitelist.basic());

            mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://fratria.ru/",
                    "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto; width: 100%;}" +
                            "iframe {display: block; max-width:100%; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;}" +
                            "</style>"
                            + "<h2>" + title.html() + "</h2>" + tfa.html() + comqqq, "text/html", "en_US", null);
        }

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}

private final WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        if (mFullScreenView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        mFullScreenView = view;
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mFullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFullScreenContainer.addView(view);
        mFullscreenViewCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();
        if (mFullScreenView == null) {
            return;
        }
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mFullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mFullScreenContainer.removeView(mFullScreenView);
        mFullscreenViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        mFullScreenView = null;
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну для начала я бы посоветовал прятать статус бар

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Тогда у видео будет достаточно высоты что бы при сохранении пропорций заполнить и ширину. Но если у экрана телефона соотношение сторон не соответствует таковому у видео, то тут уж без черных полос не обойдется...

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил в метод onShowCustomView + убрал android:padding="8dp и все стало как нужно!